# How to save the url of requests to an apache in to database with php?

Tags: php, sql, apache, url, logging

I wanted to save the requested urls of my website in to a table in database.

For example if user1 requests the url `myserver.com/images/header.png`, the below record should be saved in to database.

```
id    user    requested_url
1     user1   /images/header.png
```

EDIT: My main problem is how to know the requested Urls and pass them to a php file!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Apaches' `mod_log_mysql` or `mod_log_sql`.
They will allow you to forward apache logs to SQL servers.

Readup:

http://onlamp.com/pub/a/apache/2005/02/10/database_logs.html?page=2

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer, but there is one step to be the Final answer ;-)
The question is:
Is it possible to log certain files into database?
e.g. the files which are not exist (404 ones) and this specific file: images/header.png

Comment: yes. the documenation of said modules should help with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to pass everything via a PHP file that has access to your user session.

First thing you need to do is setup a .htaccess file to redirect everything to a specific PHP file.

Then program to pass the requested file to the user and also log the request.

Make sure when you do this you exclude the files that are accessed by regular site pages so the script still works as usual just the non page elements like images css js pass through this file.

Add to one of your main script files the same code that logs request to the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DBMS and query to it in order to save the data in your desired table. In MySQL it would be:

`INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ( NULL , 'user1', '/images/header.png');`

Edit, since someone gave me a -1.
You should add this query-call in your index.php or whatever FrontPage Controller-page you are using to handle all your pages. Using htaccess you can also log 'hotlinked' files.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think I couldn't explain my problem accurately. Actually, I don't have any problem with MySQL and DB queries. My main problem is how to know the requested Urls and pass them to a php file!

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the database first and then insert, here is a an example using PDO:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'; // mysql
//$dsn = 'mssql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb'; // mssql
$db = new PDO($dsn, 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ( 0 , :user, :page)");
$stmt->execute(array(':user' => $username, ':page' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

I'm guessing first field should be ID and auto increment.

The connection and insert must be in every page, maybe a global file.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think I couldn't explain my problem accurately. Actually, I don't have any problem with MySQL and DB queries. My main problem is how to know the requested Urls and pass them to a php file!

Comment: You didn't read my answer, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the sollution

Comment: oh sorry!
but how can I log static files? this code should be in a php file. and the `REQUEST_URI` that you mentioned is the url of that php file.

Comment: in the header of a static file?!!